# Will the Monster Book ever come back?

Tags: maplestory

Since the Big Bang patch, the Monster Book has vanished.

Is this temporary because of all the changes or was I one of the few that loved this feature?

Comment: Just curious what you think about the monster collection, which replaced the book ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's not coming back, at least in KMS it's not coming.